# stitching detail parameters

Tags: opencv, parameters

I encounter a problem, when i run stitching detail program. Maybe i understand all parameters, except `--save_paragraph`. I dont know what command should i write. And i know also that there should be a dot file, but the command

```
stitching_detail --save_paragraph a.dot 1.png 2.png
```

doesn't work. And its returns as error:

```
can't open image --save_paragraph
```

and the program's can be found [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp)

thanks for answering:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no flag `--save_paragraph`

The correct flag is `--save_graph`

Comment: 1 --save_graph a.dot 1.png 2.png

Comment: @FeiLi if it works accept the answer and give a +1 to it, this way you are telling other people with similar problems what is the answer that worked for you

Comment: :( Maybe I need at least 15 reputation. I am terribly sorry.